# Inserting items on with braces

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm doing a web page inserting, fetching and deleting items on mongodb JSON, the problem is i can't insert the way my db wants, for example  i have this on my db,

```
 "marital" : "unmarried",
    "name" : {
        "first" : "Lorna",
        "last" : "Charlish"
    },
```

so, when i want to insert the name i've tried with

```
name.first: req.param('name.first'),
name.last:req.param('name.last'),
```

but i get an error saying "name >.< first: req.param('name.first')"
Syntax error: unexpected token .

so then i tried with

```
app.post('/employee/new', function(req, res){
    employeeProvider.save({
        name: [req.param('name.first'), req.param('name.last')],
        marital: req.param('marital'),
    }, function(error, docs) {
            res.redirect('/')
    });
});
```

and it did insert but not the way i want:

```
 "name" : [ 
        "Jonah", 
        "Santos"
    ]
```

I've tried to change the code to braces but it didn't work, just with brackets, and i don't know why!

So i don't know how to insert with the first format.. i'm just starting with this, i will be entirely glad if someone can help me, thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

While i was writing the question i figure it out and i tried it, so i will write my own answer so someday it will help someone,

```
name: ({first: req.param('name.first'), last: req.param('name.last')}),
        marital: req.param('marital'),
```

sorry the bad english.